# JProfiler Remote Application Integration in web sphere 8.5 with JVM installed in different node

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, jprofiler

We are using Web Sphere 8.5 and JProfiler 8.1. I want to hook the JVM runnning in Web Sphere 8.5. JVM is installed in the node(machine) other than the node where Web Sphere is installed.

My doubt is which machine name(from below) i have to provide while using Websphere integration wizard (Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration) in JProfiler. Where the JProfiler agent to be installed from the below machine?

1. Host/Machine where JVM is installed( where Server.xml resides)
2. Host/Machine where Web Sphere is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the host name where the JVM is installed. JProfiler connects to the profiled JVM, not to the WebSphere admin server.